# How to turn multiple find and replaces into more efficient loop

Tags: excel, vba

Below is what I have in the middle of a bigger macro I've made. Creating loops and especially inserting them into larger macros successfully is something I don't know how to do. Any help is appreciated

F column has a header. How far the rows could be occupied is dynamic. When I made this I selected the entire column instead of offset 1 cell down control shift down to select simply because the input was small enough it didn't matter. Now the inputs are bigger and are slowing everything down.

```
 ' remove FIRST style tags from description *Add new ones here*
    Sheets("Columns").Select
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="<span style*>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    '2
        Sheets("Columns").Select
        Columns("F:F").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="<div style=*>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

    '3
        Sheets("Columns").Select
        Columns("F:F").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="<p style*>", Replacement:="<p>", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

...

    '18
        Sheets("Columns").Select
        Columns("F:F").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="<tbody>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Below is new code

```
 Sub Sample()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer
    Dim Ar(1 To 17) As String '~~> 4 to number of items
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Ar2(1) As String '~~> 1 to number of items
    Dim a As Long
    Ar(1) = "<span style*>"
    Ar(2) = "<div>"
    Ar(3) = "<div style=*>"
    Ar(4) = "<tbody>"
    Ar(5) = "</div>"
    Ar(6) = "<ul style=*>"
    Ar(7) = "<li style=*>"
    Ar(8) = "<table style*>"
    Ar(9) = "<col style*>"
    Ar(10) = "<tr style=*>"
    Ar(11) = "<td class=*>"
    Ar(12) = "<colgroup>"
    Ar(13) = "</colgroup>"
    Ar(14) = "</tbody>"
    Ar(15) = "</td>"
    Ar(16) = "</tr>"
    Ar(17) = "</table>"

    For i = 1 To UBound(Ar)
        Sheets("Columns").Columns(6).Replace What:=Ar(i), _
                                             Replacement:="", _
                                             LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                             MatchCase:=False, _
                                             SearchFormat:=False, _
                                             ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i
    Ar2(1) = "<p style*>"
    For a = 1 To UBound(Ar2)
        Sheets("Columns").Columns(6).Replace What:=Ar2(a), _
                                             Replacement:="<p>", _
                                             LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                             MatchCase:=False, _
                                             SearchFormat:=False, _
                                             ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next a

    'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Store all the search items in an array and then replace them in a loop. For example (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar(1 To 4) As String '~~> 4 to number of items
    Dim i As Long

    Ar(1) = "<span style*>"
    Ar(2) = "<p style*>"
    Ar(3) = "<div style=*>"
    Ar(4) = "<tbody>"

    For i = 1 To Ubound(Ar)
        Sheets("Columns").Columns(6).Replace What:=Ar(i), _
                                             Replacement:="", _
                                             LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                             MatchCase:=False, _
                                             SearchFormat:=False, _
                                             ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you'll need a replace array too as the third one is not replaced with nothing (unless that's a typo).

Comment: True that :) Depending on how many such scenarios are present, one may or may not need a repalcement array

Comment: My code above takes 253s to complete. Yours takes 231s but when I try to add a second array it jumps to 263s to complete https://imgur.com/a/SzKvtIh am I writing this the way you mean? https://imgur.com/a/SzKvtIh

Comment: 231? how big is your data? If it is huge, you may want to transfer the data from the column to an array and then then work on that?

Comment: Admittedly this data is unique and unusually large from my usual input (<50k rows) it is 693,336 rows; I understand I can use other editors; This is more like an exercise in efficiency and trying to learn something new; arrays; something ive not used before. At this point it might be more appropriate to post to code review. Thanks for your help